# How to parse string to AnnualDate in NodaTime

Tags: nodatime

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how to parse the annual date string, e.g. `09-01` to `AnnualDate`.
I'm saving `AnnualDate` as a string in the database and I need to convert it to `AnnualDate` when implementing custom conversion in EF.

The only constructor `AnnualDate` has is `AnnualDate(int, int)` and I cannot find the parse method anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as with all other NodaTime types - you use a pattern, in this case `NodaTime.Text.AnnualDatePattern`.

So:

```cs
var result = AnnualDatePattern.Iso.Parse(text);
if (result.Success)
{
    var annualDate = result.Value;
    ...
}
else
{
    // Handle failure
}
```